# Will IntegrationFlowContext.remove() destroys currently running IntegrationFlow abruptly?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, outlook, spring-integration, imap

**Background:** I am using Spring Integration to poll 3 mailboxes (**outlook365**) via InboundChannelAdaper (IMAP). I defined 3 adapters for this. I am using **Delayer** component as well. Polling is working **fine** till now.

**Problem:** Microsoft is going to disable **basic authentication** soon, so I need to modify this email polling code to use **oAuth2** authorization. Oauth2 accessToken expires after some period. I need to **keep refresh accessToken** at regular intervals.

**Solution Attempting:** Use [dynamic/runtime flow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows) via IntegrationFlowContext, register and **remove** InboundChannelAdapers ( ie. whole IntegrationFlow ) whenever I get new/refreshed accessToken.

Please assume below **scenario**:

1. **Existing** IntegrationFlows are processing some emails **currently** or **waiting in Delayer** to be processed after configured **delay of 3 mins**.
2. When I call IntegrationFlowContext.remove() and trying to destroy **currently running IntegrationFlow beans**, what will happen to those **emails are under processing now**?

**Questions:**

1. Will that running IntegrationFlow ends **abruptly** and mails under processing will be lost?
2. **Or** IntegrationFlowContext **will wait** for the current process to be completed before destroying IntegrationFlow ?
3. Is there **any other way** to use Oauth2 in Spring Integration?

**PS:** I need to use [**client-credentials-grant-flow**](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow) because there is no GUI involved in this client-app described above.

Answer (score 0):

I fight with this for a couple of days, I've never used Spring integration or Integration flow before, I dynamically create the flows for each user that connects to the application.

To your questions:

1. As far as I know everything in the integration flow is wrapped around at least an error channel to prevent this scenario and each run(cycle) will go until it gets an exception or a valid message or handler.
2. I notice after the registration the flow will start and run before any other step like removing the flow after registering in the context.

I also address AuthenticationFailedException from IMAP server:

In this case, I try to renew the token for the user if he was using OAuth.